# android приложение - парсер сайта

Tags: python, android, kivy, webview

Нужно спарсить сайт, а именно: 1.загрузить изображение (нажимая на кнопку программно). 2.получить ссылку загруженного изображения.

Вся проблема заключается в том, что это нужно проделать в ОС android.
На ПК я использую `selenium` и все прекрасно, но для андроид системы, selenium не работает так как нужно, так как например у меня в телеоне нет браузера `Chrome` или `Firefox`.
По этому вопрос, есть ли альтернатива? Возможно ли это проделать с помощью библиотеки `webview-android`? (для компиляции кода использую buildozer)
Так же мне нужно это окно браузера скрыть, чтобы пользователь не видил и не учавствовал в процессе (в `selenium` это возможно).